# App Crashes Right Away

Tags: android

I'm extremely new to Android so chances are I'm probably not doing something simple that's giving me this problem.  As soon as I try to run my app, it shuts down immediately, I have no idea why.

Here's my Java code:

```
package com.example.androidside;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    ActivityManager am;
    int s;
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l = WhatchyaDoin();
        s = l.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "" + l.get(i));
        }
    }
    public List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> WhatchyaDoin() {
        return(am.getRunningAppProcesses());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us better understand any problems you may have, it would be helpful to post as much detail as possible, including LogCat errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing `am` and are getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `WhatchayDoin()` from `onCreate()`.

You should learn how to read the logcat output from your program. (In Eclipse, you can open the logcat view by going to Window->Show View->Other and then navigating to Android->LogCat. That will often tell you what's going on. If you can't figure it out, then, when you post questions about Android crashes, always include the relevant logcat output.

You can initialize `am` in `onCreate()` with:

```
am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Oh okay, I kept thinking it was something to do with my ActivityManager but I couldn't find anything online about it.  If you don't mind me asking, can you explain the bit of code you provided for me?  I understand that you have to initiate the Activity Manager but I'm not quite understanding the way in which you did it.

Comment: @user1907350 - [`getSystemService(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) is a method in the `Activity` class, used to obtain references to a wide range of service objects, including `ActivityManager`. Since the method is declared to returns an `Object`, you need to cast it to the specific type of `Object` that the docs say that it returns for whatever argument you pass. `ACTIVITY_SERVICE` is just a constant defined to be the string `"activity"` that your activity inherits from the `Context` class.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot Ted, you've been a tremendous help.  This is actually the very beginning of a project that I'm working on with a few other people at my college, this android app being just one piece.  I saw on your profile that you develop educational apps, so I think what we're doing might interest you.  We're basically trying to develop a system so that students can use their android devices in class, for lecture and tests.  The app will monitor what is running on the students phone, and that information will be sent to a server where the teacher can monitor via a Java Servlet/Website.

Comment: @AaronStephens - That's interesting. Kind of an anti-cheating system, I gather?

Comment: Yes basically.  We want to enable students and teachers to use their smart phones, tablets, etc. in the classroom, because there is so much great content that is already out there, easily accessible, and usually very cheap.  At the same time, we want the teacher to not have to worry about the devices being distractions or used for cheating.

Comment: @AaronStephens - Makes sense. Good luck with your project.